# How can I edit or strip glyphs from a ttf (TrueType Font) file?

Tags: iphone, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to package up PT Sans for an iPhone application, but I only want the basic latin part.  It was designed for handling all the minority languages of Russia (so think HUGE file).  I'm mostly concerned about file size, and I'm happy to use a script or an editor, which ever works.  The question is, what is the easiest way to do this, preferably for free?  I'd also take an answer that allows me to package it a lot smaller in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) is the only free tool that I am aware of, and it is pretty clunky.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost impossible to get to build correctly for the mac as well.  I've been struggling with it for 45 minutes.  :(

Comment: install macports then just type sudo port install fontforge

Comment: After using macports, things weren't too bad!  I managed to reduce my font filesize from ~2 MB for all my fonts to about 500k.  Nice!